# Dynamic columns as a result of group

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

please help to solve next problem:

I have a df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Contract': ['contract1', 'contract1', 'contract1', 'contract2',
                     'contract2', 'contract3', 'contract3', 'contract3'],
               'Customer': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Ashley', 'Bill',
                     'John', 'Harry', 'Holley', 'Bob'],
               'Customer_id': ['id0001', 'id0002', 'id0003', 'id0004',
                     'id0005', 'id0006', 'id0007', 'id0001'],
                })
```

the output is

[image]

My goal is to get result as shown bellow

[image]

I think I should use somekind of function while iterating but on other hand I have a filling that there is a simpler way of solving it.

In both cases I dont know where to start, please help as I am only starting to leran to use Python.

The second task I want to do is to see in another table that group1 and group2 is also linked as Bob is a customer in both groups.

Any help is appreciated )

Comment: Your sample `df` is giving the desired output :P

Comment: @Alanagh, can you please provide the correct sample data?

Comment: Oooops sorry )))
Changed to correct sample. sorry....

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about grouping by contract.
Let's rename the Contract column to Group, and replace its elements accordingly.

```py
df.rename({'Contract':'Group'},axis=1, inplace=True)
df['Group'] = df.Group.apply(lambda x : x.replace('contract', 'group'))
df
```

Group by`Customer`, and apply a lambda function that will join every group's members together (comma separated).

```py
dfa = df.groupby('Group')['Customer'].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))
```

`dfa` looks like this:

```
Group
group1     Bob, Jane, Ashley
group2            Bill, John
group3    Harry, Holley, Bob
```

Group by `Customer_id`, join them together (comma separated), then split them again, and convert to a Pandas Series.

```py
# note:  there's probably a cleaner way to do this, but this came first to mind
dfb = df.groupby('Group')['Customer_id']\
    .apply(lambda x: ",".join(x))\
    .apply(lambda x : x.split(','))\
    .apply(pd.Series)
dfb.columns = ['Customer_id{}'.format(i) for i in dfb.columns]
```

`dfb` looks like this:

```
       Customer_id0 Customer_id1 Customer_id2
Group                                        
group1       id0001       id0002       id0003
group2       id0004       id0005          NaN
group3       id0006       id0007       id0001
```

Finally, you want to merge them together.

```py
dfc = dfb.merge(dfa, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

The final result, `dfc`, then looks like:

```
       Customer_id0 Customer_id1 Customer_id2            Customer
Group                                                            
group1       id0001       id0002       id0003   Bob, Jane, Ashley
group2       id0004       id0005          NaN          Bill, John
group3       id0006       id0007       id0001  Harry, Holley, Bob
```